# sed regex capturing group outputting whole input

Tags: bash, date, sed

I'm trying to use **sed** in order to get following output > `09 Aug 2017 14:15:11` from the string that looks like this  `09/Aug/2017:14:15:11`

when I use following code

```
sed 's/^\(\d+\)\/\(\w+\)\/\(\d+\)\:\(.*\)$/\1 /p' <(echo "09/Aug/2017:14:15:11")
```

I get whole input string as an output:
`09/Aug/2017:14:15:11`

Im doing this in order to execute `date -d` command on the result since `date -d 09/Aug/2017:14:15:11 +%s` is giving me this error: `date: invalid date ‘09/Aug/2017:14:15:11’`.
If you have other suggestion rather than using **sed** dont hesitate to make an suggestion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
$ echo "09/Aug/2017:14:15:11" | sed -e 's#/# #g' -e 's/:/ /'
09 Aug 2017 14:15:11
```

We use two [search and replace](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) commands here, one running after the other. The first one to replace all (notice the global flag, `g`) slashes with spaces (`/` → ), and the second one to replace just the first colon (`:` → ) (notice the lack of `g` flag). Both are search and replace commands (`s`), but the first one uses `#` as separator instead of the standard `/`, so we don't have to escape the slash we are searching.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, this really helps! Could you by any chance explain how these expressions `-e 's#/# #g' -e 's/:/ /'` work exactly? @randomir
*edit* just refreshed and noted your edit, thanks, amazing!

Comment: I've expanded the explanation a bit. Is it clearer now?

Comment: most certainly, short and straight to the point, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think command below is better:

```
date "+%d %h %Y %H:%M:%S"
```

Comment: The OP wants to transform an existing date string, *not* to print the current date in a specific format.